# How to set environment variables containing "!" in Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've been stuck on this for ages and I can't find a solution. I've set up environment variables in the `~/.zshrc` file and exported them correctly.

Now when I try these commands for heroku setup it works for the email address but when I enter it for the password it removes the `!` at the end of my password.

input:

```
heroku config:set EMAIL_HOST_USER="myemail@gmail.com"
heroku config:set EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="mypassword!"
```

output:

```
Setting EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD and restarting ⬢ <app-name>... done, v45
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD: mypassword
```

Can anyone explain why this may be happening?

I have also tried,

```
heroku config:add
```

but the exclamation mark is also removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many shells, [including zsh](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2007/msg00223.html) and [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33339/12606), interpret exclamation points as history expansion characters.

In both of those shells you should be able to single quote (`'`) the value to get it to work:

```
heroku config:set EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='mypassword!'
```

Double quotes (`"`) won't work.

As noted in that mailing list post, if you want to completely disable this feature in zsh you can do so with

```
unsetopt banghistory
```

And in bash [you can do](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

```
set +H
```

or

```
set +histexpand
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered you can edit your Heroku config variables in your settings of your project. https://dashboard.heroku.com/

I would still like to know how come the '!' would not save if anyone stumbles across this post and knows the answer :)